# add item count to LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, sharepoint

I have a problem I cant wrap my head around.

I have a Sharepoint List of Items, which have Categories. I want to read all Categories and count how often, they occur.

In another method, I want to take the categoryCount, divide it by the total number of tickets and multiply by 100 to get a percentage.

The problem is the Count.

This is my query so far:

```
public IEnumerable<KategorieVM> GetAllCategories()
{
int counter = 0;
var result = (from t in Tickets
where t.Kategorie != Kategorie.Invalid && t.Kategorie != Kategorie.None && t.Kategorie != null
select new KategorieVM() { _name = t.Kategorie.ToString(), _val = counter++ });


return result;
}
```

the problem is, I can't use counter++. Is there a clean workaround? The option to build a query for the purpose of counting each category is not a valid option. The list has 15000 Listitems and growing. In the end I need to iterate through every category and call the query to count the tickets which just takes about 3 minutes.
So counting the cateogry in one query is mandatory.

Any help is highly appreciated.

/edit: for the sake of clearity:
the counter++ as count was just a brainfart - I dont know why I tried it; this would have resulted in an index. I needed a way to count how often the 'category' occured in those 15k entries.

Comment: Please, make explicit do you want each resulting item to have it's position or the count of a sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to perform the `Count` within the query itself:

```
return Tickets
           .Where(t =>  t.Kategorie != Kategorie.Invalid && t.Kategorie != Kategorie.None && t.Kategorie != null)
           .GroupBy(t => t.Kategorie.ToString())
           .Select(g => new KategorieVM() { _name = g.Key, _val = g.Count() });
```

Comment: @Serv Yes - if you want to make counts, you need to "group" the items.  `GroupBy` is the appropriate method in that case.